# How to find out if a set spans a given VECTOR space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to figure out how to solve these questions.

I saw an example, but it didn't clarify anything.

1) Does ***B*** = { $\begin{bmatrix} 2&2\\ 4&3 \end{bmatrix} $,
$\begin{bmatrix} 2&1\\ 3&2 \end{bmatrix} $,
$\begin{bmatrix} 3&1\\ 1&-2 \end{bmatrix} $} span $M_{2\times 2}$ (**R**)

2) Does ***C*** = {1-x, 3+2x+$5x^2$, 3+x+$4x^2$ } span *P*$_2$(**R**)

What would I keep on the RHS if I were to make the given vectors/matrices/polynomials linear combinations?

Comment: $M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb R )$ is four dimensional, so there is no way three vectors can span the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can define a linear transformation $T:M_{2\times 2}\to \mathbb{R}^4$ when arranging the matrices (e.g.,) by columns, such that the first matrix becomes $(2,4,2,3)$. And then check whether your vectors are linearly independent. But, in your case, you have only three "vectors" in $\mathcal{B}$, where in order to span $M_{2\times 2}$ you should have $4$ independent vectors ($\dim(M_{2\times 2}) = 4$). So, $M_{2 \times 2} \nsubseteq \mathcal{B}$.

2) You can define analogous transformation $T:P_{2}(x) \to \mathbb{R}^3$, and check linear dependence. Or alternatively, check explicitly  whether you can span every vector in $P_{2}(x)$, i.e., checking whether 
$$
a_3x^2+a_2x+a_1 = b_1(1-x) + b_2(3+2x+5x^2) + b_3(3+x+4x^2)
$$
has a unique solution.

Of course in similar direct fashion you can solve $(1)$ as well.

Comment: If I try and span every vector of a3x2+a2x+a1=b1(1−x)+b2(3+2x+5x2)+b3(3+x+4x2); only to get infinitely many solutions, does that mean that the set spans the vector space? or not?

Comment: If it is not unique then it don't spans the vector space.

Answer (score 3):

While in the abstract one can truly say that 3 vectors cannot span a 4-dimensional space, it is worthwhile to restate each of your two problems in a more concrete fashion as systems of linear equations.

For example, your question 1) can be translated into linear equations in a few steps:

1. For any matrix $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$, must the following matrix equation in the three unknowns $x,y,z$ always have a solution:
   $$x \pmatrix{2 & 2 \\ 4 & 3} + y \pmatrix{2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2} + z \pmatrix{3 & 1 \\ 1 & -2} = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}
   $$

Equivalently,

2. For any four numbers $a,b,c,d$, must the following system of four equations in the three unknowns $x,y,z$ always have a solution:
   $$2x + 2y + 3z = a
   $$
   $$2x + 1y + 1z = b
   $$
   $$4x + 3y + 1z = c
   $$
   $$3x + 2y - 2z = d
   $$

Presumably you know that this system of equations is overdetermined, since there are more equations than unknowns. Therefore one can find values of $a,b,c,d$, using row reduction methods for example, such that this system of equations has no solution.

Answer (score 2):

For the first case,  surely  not. The 2x2 matrices is a space of dimension 4 and you have only '3 vectors'  to span it.

Comment: So because the dimension of the space is 4, and there are only 3 matrices within the set, I can simply say "a set of fewer than 4 vectors in a vector space with dimension 4 cannot span the vector space" ?